# Domain security events stopped logging

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I had noticed that security events on all domain controllers stopped logging. This occurred after I did some cleanup on GPO, I noticed that we had a login events GPO, but also this was enabled in the default GPO. So I unlinked the Login events GPO. If I look at the security events in comp management I have a fair few Audit policy change event 4719 and nothing since then. I did re link the Logon events GPO back but still no events populating.
Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I had uninked a high security GP without realising, added it back and then logs started to populate again.